How to get the scheduled iFlows in SAP CPI set run once for tracing the recent changes?
In the CPI iFlow where the scheduler is set, I have externalized and set it to run once, because I want to download the payload, because in the UAT EC, I have done some changes so what to know how they are affecting, but in CPI the jobs are not running even after set to run once, they are after using run once they are deploying at their scheduled time, what to do ?
How to make the jobs run without actually editing the iFlows maximum?
I want to know the changes, I made in new hire in EC to reflect in the payload, but the jobs are not running, and I am restricted to edit any iFlow rather than run once.
